# Type checking as opposed to multiple functions?

Tags: python, coding-style, dynamic-typing

In statically-typed languages such as Java, code such as the following is common (not much of a realistic example, I know):

```
public String flip(String text) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        result += text.charAt(i);
    } 
    return result;
}

public int flip(int value) {
    return (-1) * value;
}
```

However in dynamic languages, there's no way to dispatch a specific method based on a parameter's type. So for example in Python 3, we'd have two options on how to do this. First is to check the type inside the function.

```
def flip(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return value[::-1]
    elif isinstance(value, int):
        return (-1) * value
    else:
        raise TypeError('Expected str or int.')
```

Second option is to have multiple functions:

```
def flip_int(value):
    return value * (-1)

def flip_str(text):
    return text[::-1]
```

(In dynamic languages such as Python we should try to employ duck-typing, but I'm talking about cases where that's not possible, such as the example above).

Which option should I prefer, and why? Also, is there a 'best-practice' for this in Python?

I'm asking especially about Python, but this is relevant I believe to any dynamic language.

Comment: The best option should be clearly apparent from looking at your two examples.  Which one is simpler, i.e. has less cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: That said, you should *prefer a single function when the behavior will only differ by type, and the multiple functions are closely related.*  In your example, it's not clearly apparent that the two functions are related at all.  They're just two functions with two different purposes that happen to have the same name prefix.  Unless they're not (are you simply changing the sign?) in which case the best approach might actually be to parse the text into an `int` and then call `flip` on the `int`.

Comment: Another thing to consider: the names `flip_int` and `flip_str` clearly denote the type that they intend to operate on.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3327219

Comment: Why not name them `negate` and `reverse` instead of overloading the word `flip` for two completely different operations?

Comment: Have you considered what would be the best option in statically typed languages that don't support overloading (like C)? Would that change what *you* feel is the 'best-practice'?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree that the best option for an interface of some code can be determined by looking at the complexity of its implementation. The interface's purpose is to hide the implementation, so simplifying the interface is a good thing, and may offset an increase in implementation complexity.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Read my second comment.

Comment: My gut response to this question is actually to challenge the frame:  Why have two functions called flip that do _entirely different_ things?  In one case "Flip" really means "Reverse", and in the other case it means "Negate".  The two things are not really semantically the same, so using functions of the same name to do them is itself the problem.

Ask yourself: if you have these two functions, what should `Flip(List<int>)` do?

Answer (score 9):

Including the type name inside the function is vastly preferable because it allows the programmer to specify precisely what they intend. It also makes your code a lot easier to test. If you do want implicit dispatch depending on the type, you can always offer an optional wrapper. So I would write your code as:

```
def flip_int(x):
  return -x

def flip_str(x):
  return x[::-1]

def flip(x):
  if isinstance(x, int): return flip_int(x)
  if isinstance(x, str): return flip_str(x)
  raise TypError("flip(x) requires x to be int or str")
```

Incidentally, you have effectively re-invented method dispatch. This run-time dispatch over function arguments is slightly different from “traditional” method dispatch in that the dispatch is handled by the function that is called, not by the value that the function is called on. In its generalization for more than one argument, this mechanism is known as *multi-methods*. The rest of this answer discusses argument-based method dispatch in the context of Java and Python.

Your Java example is exhibits *function overloading*, also known as *ad-hoc polymorphism*. In most languages, ad-hoc polymorphism is part of static dispatch, i.e. the overload is resolved at compile-time. When your declare two functions

```
String flip(String);
int flip(int);
```

the compiler recognizes them as two distinct functions that happen to share a name. So the compiler would store it as something like

```
flip = flip_String | flip_int;
String flip_String(String);
int flip_int(int);
```

When the compiler then parses a function call `flip(x)`, it will first resolve the static type of `x`. Because `flip` is overloaded, it will try to see which overloads actually match. How that works depends on the exact rules of the language. E.g. some languages allow implicit conversions, so the types might not match exactly. In type systems with subtyping, a type will also match all its base types. This can cause multiple overloads to be legal call targets, so many languages have some kind of ranking method. E.g. calls that don't require conversions are preferred. With subtyping, the most specific type is preferred.

So finally, if the term `x` has type `String`, the overload `flip_String` would be chosen.

Of course, the static nature of this dispatch restricts its expressiveness. E.g. assume that class `A` inherits from `B`. We now have two functions `void f(A)` and `void f(B)`. Given `B b = new A(); f(b)`, the overload chosen will always be `f(B)` since that's the static type of the variable `b`, even if its runtime value is of the more specific type `A`.

Everything<sup>[1]</sup> that can be done statically in ahead of time compilation can also be done dynamically during runtime. While there might not be a static type in dynamic languages, the dispatch mechanism now has access to the precise dynamic type of a value. This means that runtime overload resolution can be more expressive than static resolution<sup>[1]</sup>: we can dispatch on the dynamic type of values. The mechanism is identical to the static version of the dispatch: the dispatch mechanism needs a set of available dispatch targets. When the overloaded function is called, the correct overload is selected.

<sup>[1]: Some languages allow return-type polymorphism, which is admittedly a bit difficult to do in dynamic languages unless the language is also lazy and supports symbolic execution.</sup>

This dynamic overload resolution is related to method dispatch. When we have a class `A` that is a subtype of class `B` and `x` is an instance of either of those classes, then `x.foo()` can do something entirely different depending on what its dynamic type is. The visitor pattern can be used to generalize this single dispatch to double dispatch, where a call `x.visit(y)` is resolved based on the dynamic type of both `x` and `y`. This can be generalized to *multimethods*, where a function is dispatched on the dynamic type of all its arguments.

Unsurprisingly, Python already has a package for multimethods:

```
from multimethods import multimethod

@multimethod(int)
def flip(x):
  return -x

@multimethod(str)
def flip(x):
  return x[::-1]

print(flip(42))
print(flip("foo"))
```

Some languages use multimethods as their primary dispatch mechanism, e.g. the Common Lisp Object System, or the Julia language. However, most cases of polymorphism can be either resolved statically, or simplified to single dispatch. Therefore, built-in language support for multimethods tends to have negligible performance impact when compared with multimethods that are added to an existing language via metaprogramming.

Implementing multi-methods can be non-trivial, because two separate overloads might look like equally good candidates. Again, assuming that `A` is a subtype of `B`:

```
void foo(A, B);
void foo(B, A);
A x; A y;
foo(x, y);
```

Both candidates would match equally well. There are various approaches to resolve this. One solution might be to find the overall “best” match using some kind of subtyping distance, but that tends to be hard to understand for programmers. It is more reasonable to look at all arguments from left to right, and order the overloads if one candidate is a better match for this single argument. E.g. in this example, the first argument is of type `A`, so `foo(A, B)` would be preferred over `foo(B, A)`. The second argument matches both of these cases and does not change the existing order.

The mentioned Python module ignores these difficulties, and instead dispatches to the *first* match, no matter how well it actually matches.
This requires a user to put the more specific cases before the more general case. The module's main dispatch logic boils down to this:

```
def __call__(self, *args):
  for types, function in self.typemap:
    if len(args) == len(types) and all(isinstance(a, t) for a, t in zip(args, types)):
      return function(*args)
  raise ValueError("multimethod: no matching method found")
```

You can see the full source yourself under [r0k3/multimethods on GitHub](https://github.com/r0k3/multimethods), or install the module via `pip install multimethods`.

Comment: The simple approach to have something like return-type polymorphism is to give the return type as an input parameter, which is generally sufficient: `(map 'string #'code-char (map 'list #'char-code "Identity"))`

Answer (score 8):

It's been a while, but in case anyone is reading this in the FUTURE...

The correct answer in 3.5+ is [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch).

```
import functools
@functools.singledispatch
def flip(arg, *args):
    raise TypeError(type(arg) + " not supported.") 
    # Or NotImplementedError, if you like.

@flip.register(int)
def flip_int(x):    # could call this function anything.
    return -x

@flip.register(str)
def flip_str(x):
    return x[::-1]
```

Comment: This is really useful. Just a couple of changes I had to make: `args*` to `*args` in the generic function signature. `str[::-1]` to `x[::-1]` in str version.

Comment: Also a couple of other useful features are 1. @register stacking (multiple types for the same function) and 2. No need to specify type in the @register decorator if the argument is annotated (ex: `flip_int(x: int)`)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can do it, doesn’t mean you should. If you have two methods with very different meanings, you should rather avoid using the same name. Worse example: Draw lines on the screen, draw a weapon to fight, draw in a game of chess.